# Get Rid PHP Warning from Other PHP files

Tags: php, css

I have wordpress plugin that generate dynamic CSS from PHP, let say the file name is dynamiccss.php. here is the code :

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
$parse_uri = explode( 'wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] );
require_once( $parse_uri[0] . 'wp-load.php' );


//CSS GOES HERE

?>
```

Everything work well, but if i use another plugin and that plugin has an error in the PHP the error message always appears in my css file, for example when I access the css file from http://domain.com/dynamiccss.php:

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  SOME PHP ERROR HERE...

My CSS CODE
```

This error message causes mess css. How to prevent this? thank you very much.

Comment: Turn off error reporting on those files

Comment: Better yet: fix the files so they don't produce an error in the first place.

Comment: Hi John, what code should be put in our file? (dinamiccss.php)

Comment: [error_reporting()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php), also available in other languages than english if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried turning off error reporting at the top of your script? Like this:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
ini_set('display_errors', 0);

header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
$parse_uri = explode( 'wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] );
require_once( $parse_uri[0] . 'wp-load.php' );


//CSS GOES HERE

?>
```